# Generate random samples using Box-Muller

Tags: random, sampling

In general, the Box-Muller algorithm samples **two** independent uniform variates on (0,1) and transforms them into **two** independent standard normal distributions via
[image] and
[image]

Is it possible to use the Box-Muller method to generate **6** iid standard normal random samples using **chi-square** and **uniform** random samples? If yes, how can we do that?

In particular, how can we extend the Box-Muller method to the $n$-dimensional case?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question and be clear as to what you want. We can use the Box-Muller method to generate two iid Standard Normal Variates from two iid Uniform $(0,1)$ Variates.

Comment: Just in case, the OP may want to have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025312/box-muller-transformation.